# Isolated scope's property does not affect its parent

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here is my code:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>   

<body>
   <div ng-controller="myController"> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="value"  restrictions error-message=errorMessage />
    <span style="color:red;margin-left:50px">{{errorMessage}}</span>
    </div>
<script>
   angular.module('myApp',[])
   .controller('myController', function ($scope){
       $scope.errorMessage="Football game";
   })
   .directive('restrictions',  function() {
            return {  
                scope: {
                  errorMessage:'='
               },    
               link:function(scope,element){ 

                  element.on('click', function(event) { 
                        event.preventDefault();  
                        console.log(scope.errorMessage);  //  Football game                 
                        scope.errorMessage="Invalid characters";                     
                        console.log(scope.errorMessage);   //Invalid characters                   
                  });
               }
            }
    });

</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

That's what I cannot explain is why `{{errorMessage}}` **does not change to "Invalid characters" and still shows "Football game"**. I think scope.errorMessage is the same with $scope.errorMessage because of `errorMessage:'='`. Also, I know that scope.$parent===$scope. Any explanation?

Comment: As you say, you have an isolated `$scope` object. It inherits from the parent, so changes from the parent will reflect in the child, but not the other way around

Comment: However, errorMessage should affect the parent because of '='

Comment: Yeah sorry I missed that one. I think you should trigger the `$digest` of angular manually, because the `on('click'..` occurs outside of it: `scope.$apply(function(){ scope.errorMessage = .. });`

Comment: //add  scope.$apply()  end of link function ..........
......element.on('click', function(event) { 
                        event.preventDefault();  
                        console.log(scope.errorMessage);  //  Football game                 
                        scope.errorMessage="Invalid characters";                     
                        console.log(scope.errorMessage);   //Invalid characters                   

scope.$apply();   // add this line
                  });

Answer (score 1):

Change your link function to:

```
link: function(scope, element) {

     element.on('click', function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         console.log(scope.errorMessage); //  Football game                 
         scope.errorMessage = "Invalid characters";
         scope.$apply(); 
         console.log(scope.errorMessage); //Invalid characters                   
     });
 }
```

Note `scope.$apply()` which forces the $digest cycle after the `click` event.

Comment: I have already tried that and it did not work. However, I have placed `scope.$apply()` at the end of the function. By placing it at the position you suggest, it works!!!    Is that crazy or does it have any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried toset $scope.$apply() ? ..cause if you want to trigger a external angular event you need it ..somthing like:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>   

<body>
   <div ng-controller="myController"> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="value"  restrictions error-message=errorMessage />
    <span style="color:red;margin-left:50px">{{errorMessage}}</span>
    </div>
<script>
   angular.module('myApp',[])
   .controller('myController', function ($scope){
       $scope.errorMessage="Football game";
   })
   .directive('restrictions',  function() {
            return {  
                scope: {
                  errorMessage:'='
               },    
               link:function(scope,element){ 



                      element.on('click', function(event) { 
                            event.preventDefault();  
                            console.log(scope.errorMessage);  //  Football game                  $scope.$apply(function(){
                            scope.errorMessage="Invalid characters";                     
                            console.log(scope.errorMessage);   //Invalid characters                   
                      });
});
               }
            }
    });

</script> 

</body>
</html>
```